# xml: mixing namespaces - can I use thymeleaf to process an XSL-FO file?

Tags: xml, xslt, thymeleaf, apache-fop

What I'd like to do is use the thymeleaf template processor to parse and perform variable substitution on a FO document.  To me, conceptually, this should work - the FO document is a valid xml file, so I should be able to run it through thymeleaf engine and have it substitute node values (for example).  What I can't seem to do is mix the namespaces appropriately.  Can someone tell me what the right syntax for this would be?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      font-size="3.6mm" font-family="Courier">
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="model" type="mypackage.Model"*/-->
    <fo:layout-master-set>
 ...
         <fo:table-cell>
             <fo:block th:text="${model.county}">
                  Chittenden
             </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
```

Or is what I'm thinking just completely wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? To me, your code looks correct. So, where does Thymeleaf fail?

Answer (score 0):

***I know its too late, but wanted to share the answer, so that others can refer it.***

You can very well use **thymeleaf** to process your **FO** files. In your case the

```
<fo:block th:text="${model.county}">
     Chittenden
</fo:block>
```

Here, You have already provided the `text content` for the tag.Hence, You don't need to provide the text content explicitly, Thymeleaf will process your `th:text="${model.county}"` and replace it in place of your text content.

Hence, The correct usage should be

```
<fo:block th:text="${model.county}"/>
```

Also,

Your Thymeleaf processor enginer should be configured as below,

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.XML);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".fo");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateProcessorEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a very old post, and I don't think I have the code anymore to test it.  However, I think you're wrong in your answer, for two reasons.  First, your Spring config is changing the extension of the file, but it should in fact be looking at an xml.  Second, I left "Chittenden" in as a test value so FO could process the original file.  It *should* be replaced when Thymeleaf evaluates the file.

Comment: IIRC, my problem was that Thymeleaf was not honoring the other namespace; specifically I needed a `<fo:block>...` to be passed to the FO processor after evaluation.

Comment: @end-user I have used the `FO` for PDF generation using `Apache FOP` and `Barcode4j`, where Thymeleaf is used to process the xml file hence the extension `FO`. Also, the values are very well getting replaced. It would be great if you can recollect the error and the requirement, as per my current code I don't find the configuration wrong and creating any issues.

Comment: If you need you can refer the project [https://github.com/devrishal/barcode-generator](https://github.com/devrishal/barcode-generator)